# What is this called in English ? (insignia)

Tags: word-usage

[image]

What is this called in English ?

Can we say insignia?

Thank you.

P.S: There is a needle at the back of this thing in order to stick it to a shirt or a jacket.

Comment: It's called a badge (or sometimes a button).

Comment: It's a lapel pin. "Insignia" applies in some cases.

Comment: @keramus It's a button.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Which one is this? BADGE or  LAPEL PIN or BUTTON?

Comment: all three, it depends on one's nationality. AmEng it's a *pin* (short for lapel pin) ;  BrEng it's a *badge*. *Lapel-pin* either dialect I guess. *Button*? Anyone's guess.

Comment: As a BrEng speaker, I would call it a pin badge, to distinguish it from sew-on badges.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "Button" is US.   If it had a politician's name on it it would be a "campaign button".

Comment: I think it's worth broaching the subject of *brooches*: items of jewellery which have similar fastenings and similar size, but which tend to be much more ornamental than the item shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only speak for American usage, but on this side of the pond, this type of item is distinctly a ***button***. Aficionados may refer to them as *pin buttons* or *pin-back buttons* but in general, it is understood from context whether one's *button* refers to a fastener keeping your clothing fixed in place or to this item, which commonly advertises a slogan or affiliation.

This usage is a shortening of *campaign button*, which dating from the election of George Washington in 1789, originally referred to decorative fasteners which were [sewn into clothing](http://archives.chicagotribune.com/1967/01/19/page/93/article/campaign-buttons-recall-our-nations-political-history). The linked article dates this particular form of this type of button— a celluloid face attaching a paper print to a metal disc, with a clasped spring pin on the back— to the McKinley campaign of 1896, but there is a [patent for the campaign button](https://www.google.com/patents/US401094) issued a few years earlier:

[image: Diagram from U.S. patent 401094, for a campaign button]

Of course, this technology has never limited to political campaigns. There is a certain stereotype of the activist or punk rocker [festooned with buttons](http://www.zimbio.com/pictures/J5cYbUv2Zdk/Focus+Political+Pins+Campaign+Buttons) or driving a car exposing [more bumper sticker than paint](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bumper-crop.jpg), slightly displaced by the phenomenon of the [awareness ribbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awareness_ribbon). But the pin-back button is used broadly in commercial marketing, and elsewhere— as [lampooned in the film *Office Space*](https://dynamicsaxtipoftheday.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/thcazb028p.jpg), for instance.

It could be called a *pin*, though this term is very broad and vague, and in AmE wearing a *pin* without other context usually refers to a *lapel pin*, for example the [flag pin](http://content.time.com/time/nation/article/0,8599,1820023,00.html) that became *de rigeur* for politicians after the September 11 attacks. These are usually smaller and attached with a non-sprung clasp or a butterfly clasp. A *badge* commonly refers to an identifying token, especially for an official, as with the *[sheriff's badge](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Sheriff_badges)*. I would probably not use *insignia*; although technically correct, outside of the military, it may be understood to refer to the symbol or mark and not necessarily the physical piece.

Comment: Can (campaign) "buttons" be purely decorative as in the OP's example?

Comment: UK [(school) badges](http://www.fattorini-schools.co.uk/) and [pop art badges](https://www.google.it/search?q=school+badges&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCYQsARqFQoTCLnotoG_4MgCFQs-FAodddgBrg&biw=1366&bih=677#tbm=isch&q=%22pop+art%22+badges)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, *button* describes the form— a metal disc with a clasped spring pin. It originated as a cheap token for political rallies, but as I noted, it can be used for anything now, not just as campaign buttons. I think most Americans would describe the "achievement badges" and "metal badges" on the page you linked generically as *pins*, being a *badge* only if they signify some particular award or achievement. *My daughter earned the chemistry badge this quarter. It's a gold pin with an Erlenmeyer flask on it.*

Comment: I gather *badge* would be the British/international term. Over here, though, I get more than twice as many Google Image Search results for "pop art button" as for "pop art badge".